# How to insert a blank line in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I am 3 weeks new to xml-xslt. I simply need to add a blank line or blank row, or skip a space between a paragraph and the following information below that paragraph. Even some of our IT guys can't figure out. So it's just not me.

```
For example this is a paragraph.
Line two of paragraph.
Line three of paragraph.

The next output should be down here, 
not up against the preceding paragraph.
```

I've tried all the supposed tags listed on the Web - however, all do not say where to put those tags. I put where I think, and they don't work. I'm all open ears and eyes to anyone who may help. Please use layman's terms for I'm not all that familiar with the jargon of xml-xslt. Thanks in advance!!! Moi in Dallas

Comment: You can emit text directly to the output using `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>`. Is that what you meant by a line break?

Comment: XSLT is used to transform XML to some target format, like HTML or  PDF (with XSL-FO as an intermediate format) or plain text or SVG. So find out which is your target format and look up any tutorial on that target format on how to lay out text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get good responses to questions here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (this is of course difficult if you have no idea where to start).  Not showing your work makes it hard for answerers to know where you're going wrong.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and I present here the answer from @Bob Dagleish's comment.  (thanks Bob).

I am converting some DITA source XML which looks a lot like HTML in some cases into LaTeX.  The problem was with paragraph "p" tags.  For LaTeX the new paragraph is indicated by a blank line.  The source would be something like this:

```
<p>paragraph one</p><p>paragraph two</p><p>paragraph three</p>
```

The template to convert this was something like

```
<xsl:template match="p">


<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this matches the "p" tag, is supposed to output two carriage returns, and then return to matching tags within the paragraph.  However the blanks are being thrown away because in XML any amount of any white space is considered the same as a single space character.  So I was getting this:

```
paragraph one paragraph two paragraph three
```

The solution suggested was to sepcifically output the return characters.  i changed the template to this:

```
<xsl:template match="p">

<xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This guarantees that two returns are placed into the output in a row, and the result looks like this in the editor:

```
paragraph one 

paragraph two 

paragraph three
```